# Postgresql server appears not to be running after install

Tags: postgresql, installation, ubuntu

I installed ubuntu 12.6 on Ubuntu 20.10. I had a postgresql version 10 once running on my system. I purged it before installation with `sudo apt --purge remove postgresql postgresql-contrib`. The package list shows:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep postgresql
ii  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql                                 1:7.0.3-0ubuntu0.20.10.1            amd64        PostgreSQL SDBC driver for LibreOffice
ii  pgdg-keyring                                                2018.2                              all          keyring for apt.postgresql.org
ii  postgresql                                                  12+216                              all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-12                                               12.6-0ubuntu0.20.10.1               amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 12 server
ii  postgresql-12-postgis-3                                     3.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu2                 amd64        Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 12
ii  postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts                             3.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu2                 all          Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 12 -- SQL scripts
ii  postgresql-client-12                                        12.6-0ubuntu0.20.10.1               amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 12
ii  postgresql-client-common                                    216                                 all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                                           216                                 all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib                                          12+216                              all          additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)
```

When I try to run `sudo -i -u postgres psql` I get:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory    
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

`nmap localhost` confirmed that port 5432 was not listened at. It is explicitly open for in and out in the firewall.

ystemctl status:

```
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2021-03-26 11:49:43 CET; 2s ago
    Process: 21416 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 21416 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 26 11:49:43 joosken systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 26 11:49:43 joosken systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

This seems that everything is ok, but it seems to finish immediately. I don't understand why.

Looking for logs in `/var/log/postgresql`. That is weird: i only find logs from postgresql-10 and they are from months ago. `pg_lsclusters` does not show any cluster.

In short: my postgres installation appears to be ok *and* a mess. What can I do to rectify this?

Comment: "What can I do to rectify this?" Troubleshoot further. Find the logs. Try starting the postgres daemon manually. Check directory and file permissions to ensure postgres can read and write what it wants to. And so on.

Comment: _pg_lsclusters does not show any cluster_: that's pretty much the answer to your question. See pg_createcluster to create a PostgreSQL instance.